# Using distinctUntilChanged with combineLatest throws Equatable error with RxSwift

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I am trying to use `distinctUntilChanged` with combineLatest, eg:

```
Observable.combineLatest(focusedCourse, infoState)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .map { focusedCourse, infoState in
       // Implementation
    }
    .bind(to: videoSource)
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

However I am getting the error:

```
Type '(BehaviorRelay<Course?>.Element, BehaviorRelay<InfoState>.Element)' cannot conform to 'Equatable'
```

I have conformed both `Course` and `InfoState` to equatable but still get this error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a tuple conforms to Equatable even if all its elements do so you have to provide the equality check to `distinctUntilChanged`:

```
Observable.combineLatest(focusedCourse, infoState)
    .distinctUntilChanged { $0 == $1 }
    .map { focusedCourse, infoState in
        // Implementation
    }
    .bind(to: videoSource)
    .disposed(by: bag)
```